# How to know when AVPlayer is ready to play and sent info to the controller

Tags: swift, streaming

I'm bulding a radio streaming app in swift. Currently is all working but i want to improve a little the user experience.

I have a RadioPlayer.swift class that handles my radio actions.

```
 import Foundation
 import AVFoundation

 class RadioPlayer {
 static let sharedInstance = RadioPlayer()
 private var player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string:"http://rfcmedia.streamguys1.com/classicrock.mp3")!)

private var isPlaying = false


func play() {
    player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: "http://rfcmedia.streamguys1.com/classicrock.mp3")!)
    player.play()
    isPlaying = true

    player.currentItem?.status

}

func pause() {
    player.pause()
    isPlaying = false
    player.replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem(nil)
}

func toggle() {
    if isPlaying == true {
        pause()
    } else {
        play()
    }
}

func currentlyPlaying() -> Bool {
    return isPlaying
}
```

Then i have a View Controller that implement that class. My objective is that when the player is loading, send a message saying that the streaming is being prepared, so the user know that have to wait (also disable the play button).

So my question is how can achieve that, in android i used broadcasts in order to send messages but i didn't found an equivalent in swift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add observers for the `AVPlayer` properties, e.g. in Swift 3:

```
player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "reasonForWaitingToPlay", options: .new, context: &observerContext)
```

Or in Swift 2, use `.New`:

```
player.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "reasonForWaitingToPlay", options: .New, context: &observerContext)
```

Note, that's using a private property to identify the context:

```
private var observerContext = 0
```

And then you can add the observer method. In Swift 3:

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    guard context == &observerContext else {
        super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath, of: object, change: change, context: context)
        return
    }

    // look at `change![.newKey]` to see what the status is, e.g.

    if keyPath == "reasonForWaitingToPlay" {
        NSLog("\(keyPath): \(change![.newKey])")
    }
}
```

Or in Swift 2:

```
override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String?, ofObject object: AnyObject?, change: [String : AnyObject]?, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
    guard context == &observerContext else {
        super.observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath, ofObject: object, change: change, context: context)
        return
    }

    // look at `change![NSKeyValueChangeNewKey]` to see what the status is, e.g.

    if keyPath == "reasonForWaitingToPlay" {
        NSLog("\(keyPath): \(change![NSKeyValueChangeNewKey])")
    }

}
```

Comment: so i have to implement the observer in the RadioPlayer class, and the the func on my viewController? Thanks a lot

Comment: Yep. Technically, you could have your view controller observe the `AVPlayer` properties directly, but it's more appropriate to have your own delegate-protocol pattern or some closure pattern by which the `RadioPlayer` can inform the `ViewController` of the key events the view controller might care about.

Comment: Yes i know, i'm trying to implement the code that you post, when i finish i will accept the answer :D

Comment: I added the observer but i'm not able to see any message, maybe i'm doing somenthing wrong.

Comment: after a few tries i was able to implement it, but now throws me "message was received but not handled."

Comment: I cannot comment on why you got this. I wonder if you replaced the `AVPlayer` without first removing the observers?. It works fine for me. See https://github.com/robertmryan/RadioPlayer for my Swift 3 example. If you want, you can upload a simple project somewhere and I can take a quick look to see if I see anything obvious.

Comment: thanks a lot for the code! reasonForWaitingToPlay is only available on IOS 10, i assume that should be an equivalent for older versions, but your code is really helpfull!

Comment: I was able to check when the player starts with the "status" key. Now i have a question, i saw that you use a "closure" to send the message to the viewController, how can i use that message in order to enable/disable a button?

Comment: You just put the code to enable/disable the button inside that closure. I change the text of a button in my closure, but you can do whatever you want in yours.

Comment: awesome, i was able to do it!! thanks a lot man, i really appreciate your help, i'm really new on ios development and this part was very tricky for me.